# Visualize clusters for K means in R

Tags: r

I am doing a project on K means clustering and I have a shopping dataset which has 17 variables and 2 million observations.

After running the K Means, I want to visualize all different combinations for the variables. For example A against B, B against C, C against D etc. Rather than doing it one by one, is there a way to plot all of them in one go?

I am using R for my coding. could anyone please suggest the best way to visualize all these clusters? I am looking for a pattern within the dataset.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you 
A

Comment: Hi, you can use the function **pairs** to produce scatter plots for each variables. But to go further in you analyses, you should use the package **Rmixmod** or **mclust** and select the model corresponding to the kmean, this 2 produces more results and scatterplots than the defaul **kmeans**.

Comment: Hi @Mamoun Benghezal, I am new to R and have very little experience. I have heard about the mclust function before, do you know where I can find some examples on how to use this function? I installed the package in R and pressed F1 to read.
the example if gives is this

mod1 = Mclust(iris[,1:4])

could you explain what does [,1:4]) this represent?

Comment: Unlike Kmeans who uses hard clustering, Mclust compute the post probability of the individuals for all the clusters that is clalled soft clustering. It also uses different models (check the help page), in the case of **iris** data, it return a model **VEV** which mean **V**ariable in volume **E**qual in shape fo the clusters and **V**ariable orientiations. Thus, in the last iteration of **Mclust** you will get postprobs which can be used to cluster you data, and it is likely that the result will be different than the classical **kmean**.

Answer (score 3):

You could just simply use `plot`

For instance:

```
km <- kmeans(iris[,-5], centers=3)

plot(iris[,-5], col=km$cluster)
```

If you plot to a large enough image or PDF file (e.g. using the `jpeg` or `pdf` command) you can then zoom in to see individual graphs more easily.

Comment: Hi thank you for your reply, I have 18 columns in total and i want to view all possible combinations to determine a good cluster or behavior from the data. What you suggested is just plotting X against Y. Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: @user2704941: nope, try the code I posted, it will plot everyone against everyone! See: http://www.r-fiddle.org/#/fiddle?id=1PF6DGI0&version=1

Comment: thank you replying, could you please clarify what is [,-5], ?

Comment: I understand kmeans(data, number of centres) but I am not sure about [,-5],  what does that represent? I have 13 columns within my dataset and each is labelled with a name. For example basket_id, product_id ...